# How to execute all objects in an array and then send response to client?

Tags: arrays, sql-server, node.js

I am new to async programming. I know this question has been asked multiple times but I am not able to understand and solve this problem, I am using nodeJs and MsSql module to connect to Sql Server.

I am writing a nodejs app, which accepts input parameters and runs in a foreach loop executing each object. My question is how can I send the response back to client once all the objects in an array have been executed. Right now I am sending response back after each object is executed.

My second question is does async programming cause deadlocks in the database?

Code below :

```
   **Post call code:**

exports.add = function (req, resp, reqbody) {
    try {
        if (!reqbody)
            throw new Error(" Dude, No data !! Send Some Data");
        var data = JSON.parse(reqbody);
        if (data) {
            data.forEach(function (obj) {
                var sql = "USE " + obj.a + " EXEC [dbo].[SP] " + obj.c+ ", " + obj.b+ ""                                      
                  db.executeSql(sql, function (data, err) {
                    if (err) {
                        responses.show500(req, resp, err)
                   }
                    else {
                        responses.send200(req, resp)

                    }
                });
            });
        }
        else {
            throw new Error("Input not valid");
        }
    }  
        catch (ex) {
        console.log(ex);
            responses.show500(req, resp, ex);
        }
};
```

**DB Call code :**

```
var db = require("../core/db");
var responses = require("../core/responses");
exports.executeSql = function (sql, callback) {

    var conn = new sqldb.Connection(settings.dbconfig);
    conn.connect()
    .then(function () {
        var req = new sqldb.Request(conn);
        req.query(sql)
        .then(function (recordset) {
            callback(recordset);
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            callback(null, err);
            return;
        });
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        callback(null, err);


    });
};
```

**UPDATE POST CALL CODE**

```
async.each(data, function (obj, callback) {
                    //console.log(obj);
                    var sql = "USE " + obj.a + " EXEC [dbo].[SP] " + obj.c+ ", " + obj.b+ ""          
                db.executeSql(sql, function (data, err) {

                    if (err) return callback(err);
                    callback();
                })  
            }, function (err) {
                if (err) {
                    console.error(err);
                    responses.show500(req, resp, err);
                } else {
                    responses.send200(req, resp);
                }

            })
```

Answer (score 0):

You need use module [async](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async).
Install it:

```
npm install async
```

And use in your code:

```
var async = require('async');
...
var data = JSON.parse(reqbody);
var queries = data.map(function (obj) {
    return "USE " + obj.a + " EXEC [dbo].[SP] " + obj.c+ ", " + obj.b+ "";
});
async.map(queies, db.executeSql, function (err, results) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }

    callback(results);
});
```

Comment: Thanks Sergy.. I will try this out as well :)